# jQuery Validate Script Error, Cannot read property call of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked everywhere online but can't figure this issue out. Simply trying to use addMethod to create custom validation checks. However I keep getting the following error!

As far as I can tell i'm including the required plugins!

Error:

> jquery.validate.js:754 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call'
>   of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element comments,
>   check the 'nourl' method.

Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol">
      <form id="form" method="" action="">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="twelvecol">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="twelvecol">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validator.addMethod("nourl", function(value, element) {
    console.log("hello");
    return !/http\:\/\/|www\.|link\=|url\=/.test(value);
  }, "No URL's" );

  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true
      },
      comments: {
        nourl: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      name: "Required Field",
      comments: "No URL's"
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for wasted post, this plugin doesn't work on jQuery v1.7.1.